# Whats the best way to tweak ruby gems for code reading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To help understand the source code of various gems I often want to place various puts statements in the source code or even try using the ruby debugger.

But whats the best way of doing this?

Do you clone the project from github and make changes locally, if so how do you "force" the use of the local cloned code over the local gem on your machine. Do I just create some scripts that explicitly require the path of the cloned repos folder?

Or do should I use rvm to create a temp gemset, download the gem and modify it directly?

Are there any other methods ive overlooked? How would this change for gems designed for use within rails projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I usually do it when I want to make changes to a Gem:

1. Fork the repository on Github
2. Check it out and create a new branch for local changes
3. Use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage dependencies for the project which uses the Gem
4. Change one line in the `Gemfile` to make it use the forked version of the Gem:

---

```
gem "thegem", :git => "git://github.com/name/thegem.git", :branch => 'mybranch'
```

or

```
gem "thegem", :git => "file:///path/to/thegem", :branch => 'mybranch'
```

with `/path/to/thegem` being the path to your local working copy.

The advantage is that you now already have a the perfect infrastructure set up for contributing your changes through a pull request :)

Comment: As suggested in the other answer, using `:path` is much more convenient in such a scenario - every change you make to the source code locally is automatically reflected in the running code.

Comment: @AleksanderPohl: As suggested in this answer, I don't quite agree. I like the advantage of having a version control in between here and seeing that the changes are done on a topic branch, it can be just thrown away afterwards (or merged as a whole into some other branch). Of course during the time of development, you don't need to always push to Github, you can just use `:git => "file:///path/to/thegem"`. It's not like `git commit -m` was an expensive operation or couldn't be bound to a shell alias.

Comment: Also, these two approaches don't exclude each other, you can also use `:path` for development and `:git` for your deployed applications.

Comment: In fact there are two commands that have to be issued `git commit` and `bundle update`. The second one is not as cheap as the first (even with the `--local` option), since Bundler has to compute the dependencies. And still, even if it was just one command, in the scenario described by the author I would prefer `:path` - these are just debugging messages, so IMHO there is no point in committing such changes into the repository. But I agree that the second version is preferred when your changes should be visible outside of your machine.

Comment: @AleksanderPohl: Hm, I didn't think about `bundle update`, that's right. I'll still leave this answer here, I think it's of general interest. OP can then choose between the two options presented here :)

Answer (score 3):

With [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

In a Rails app simply edit the Gemfile and add:

```
  gem "gem_name", :path => "~/MyGems/gem_name"
```

---

PS: [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) work with any Ruby project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rvm to create a temp gemset, download the gem and modify it directly. A fast way to view/modify a gem is using [gemedit](http://gemedit.rubyforge.org/) :

Install:

- gem install gemedit

Usage:

- gem edit devise
- or: gem edit devise -e mate